# Android WebView is loading too slow

Tags: java, android, performance, webview

For loading webview in android application it takes around 30 to 40 seconds for loading URL. Can any once please help!!
**My code:**

```
this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(
                WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Also tried with `LOAD_NO_CACHE` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebViews will be little slower than the browser as here every activity has to have a callback to the Android app layer.